How to setup Apps & Infrastructure using kubernetes
I am currently trying to figure out the best way to setup a combnination of services and apps on kubernetes.  Ideally using Ansible but thats not the purpose of the question.  The question is more to do with what is the best way to divide up the problem.
The application architecture is such that there is separation of the UI from the database access code, from the base services. E.g.

I have one Symfony app to provide UI which is exposed to the outside world.  It calls several other symfony projects using API calls, these API services have connection to shared mysql instances in the background. Each app is a separate github project.

in development I am running all of the apps together with containers for the DB and mail system and use different ports on the machine to access each of the API services.

Each of the apps is somewhat self contained in that they need a php-fpm process and their composer dependendces loaded and not much else.

I want to be able to scale the app I'm not sure how to divide it up.  Do i create a container with all of the services in it and then have multiple instances behind a load balancer or do i have a load balancer for each app and have each container just be one app that i can scale individually.

I really want the API apps to be invisible to the outside world and so see them on an internal network.

In each case how do i make the database services (2 of these) available only to the internal network.

I have a RPI kluster setup as an experiment with k3S, helm, ArgoCD configured but I am failing to figure out the best architecture to move the experiment forward.


Currently working as the following.

www app process running on Apache/ nginx and php-fpm process (UI app) accessed by the outside world
API processes running as Vhosts on Apache on Ports 8000, 8001 only listen to the internal network
Docker-compose.yml with containers that create a MYSQL db and Mail Server (currently a mail catcher) the ports 3306 and 25 are exposed for the smyfony apps to access.

Thoughts ?

Who -1's a question without trying to help !!!
